# JSoup runs very slow

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to use Jsoup to parse html from a website to extract img elements, but it runs very slowly

```
  try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(webUrl).get();
        Elements imgElements = doc.select("img");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Log: Time run finish 11289.0

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup loads the image over the **internet** so it will take as long as it takes to **fetch the page over internet** and **parse it.**

You should try loading the page locally and from file and see if there's somekind of complexities in the document which causes the Jsoup to take a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I need a way faster. do you known?